# React Native. Hiding item from BottomTab.Navigator in react-navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

Let's say I have 3 pages. `Home`, `Settings`, `Page`.

I have

```
<BottomTab.Navigator>
  <BottomTab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}/>
  <BottomTab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen}/>
  <BottomTab.Screen name="Page" component={PageScreen}/>
</BottomTab.Navigator>
```

All 3 of them are shown in bottom navigation.

I want to access `Home` and `Settings` from bottom navigation and `Page` from link within `Home` page.

My question is there a way to hide `Page` from bottom navigation but still link to it from other pages and pass props and data to it?

I tried removing `Page` from `<BottomTab.Screen>` but then I can't use `navigation.navigate("Page")` to navigate to page, and I need this so I can pass props and data to that page

Here is some code from app. This code is generated with expo

```js
// App.js
render (
<NavigationContainer
          ref={containerRef}
          initialState={initialNavigationState}
        >
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </View>
)
```

```js
//bottomTabNavigator component
<RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName={INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME}>
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Get Started",
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="md-code-working" />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarVisible: false,
          title: "Your Profile",
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="md-book" />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </RootStack.Navigator>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but i think this is what you are looking for.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/

After installing everything, you can do something like this

```
const RootStackNavigator = () => {
    return(
        <RootStack.Navigator>
            <RootStack.Screen name="main" component = {BottomStackScreen}/>
            <RootStack.Screen name="Page" component={PageScreen} />
        </RootStack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

So, in your code you can switch your app.js to:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
   <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
   <Stack.Screen name="Page" component={PageScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Then you can navigate to the Page by using `this.props.navigation.navigate("Page");`

Comment: This is what I have now. And it renders ```Home```, ```Settings``` and ```Page``` onto bottom navigation. I just want it to render ```Home``` and ```Settings```

Comment: Would you mind posting your whole code? Because it depends how you structure it and what is inside your render() function. If you have your bottom navigator inside your render() it will render your bottom stack navigator only. If you have your root stack inside your render, it will render your root stack.

Comment: @MiletaDulovic So just to confirm, you want to only show 2 bottom stack navigation, Home and Screen, but you want Home and screen to both be able to access Page. Coreect?

Comment: @MiletaDulovic Edited my answer

Comment: I am sorry for late answer. This is it. It works. Thank you :)